# Marker not showing up on GMSPanoramaView

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a drop dead simple test app in which i execute the following code

```
    let marker = GMSMarker(position:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(33.987884, -118.474434))
    marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImageWithColor(UIColor.redColor())
    marker.panoramaView = panoramaView;
    marker.snippet = "I am Here!"

    panoramaView.moveNearCoordinate(marker.position)
```

If i move the coordinate to some other street off the beach i can see the marker just fine.    But from the code above I don't see anything.   Does anybody know why I can get an area to show up fine in a GMSPanoramaView however placing a marker there does not work?

Answer (score 1):

I think some implementation was not done. Not sure what are those implementation but I found some tutorials regarding your issue. Or according to the document "Note that if the marker's position is too far away from the panoramaView's current panorama location, it will not be displayed as it will be too small".

Checking the [Street View locations and point-of-view (POV)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/streetview):

```
GMSPanoramaView *panoView_;
panoView_.camera = [GMSPanoramaCamera cameraWithHeading:180
                                              pitch:-10
                                               zoom:1];
```

Markers within Street View

```
// Create a marker at the Eiffel Tower
CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(48.858,2.294);
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];

// Add the marker to a GMSPanoramaView object named panoView_
marker.panoramaView = panoView_;

// Add the marker to a GMSMapView object named mapView_
marker.map = mapView_;
```

That's the first option, another option is `Google Maps JavaScript API` inside a `WebView`. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-overlays

```
var panorama;

function initMap() {
  var astorPlace = {lat: 40.729884, lng: -73.990988};

  // Set up the map
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: astorPlace,
    zoom: 18,
    streetViewControl: false
  });

  // Set up the markers on the map
  var cafeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: 40.730031, lng: -73.991428},
      map: map,
      icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=cafe|FFFF00',
      title: 'Cafe'
  });

  var bankMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: 40.729681, lng: -73.991138},
      map: map,
      icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=dollar|FFFF00',
      title: 'Bank'
  });

  var busMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: 40.729559, lng: -73.990741},
      map: map,
      icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=bus|FFFF00',
      title: 'Bus Stop'
  });

  // We get the map's default panorama and set up some defaults.
  // Note that we don't yet set it visible.
  panorama = map.getStreetView();
  panorama.setPosition(astorPlace);
  panorama.setPov(/** @type {google.maps.StreetViewPov} */({
    heading: 265,
    pitch: 0
  }));
}

function toggleStreetView() {
  var toggle = panorama.getVisible();
  if (toggle == false) {
    panorama.setVisible(true);
  } else {
    panorama.setVisible(false);
  }
}
```

Here are links for tutorials and `repo` of the codes

- http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2013/09/sun-surveyor-shines-with-street-view.html
- https://github.com/ratana/streetview-panorama-demo
  I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but as I have shown in the code I am moving directly next to the marker, so distance away is not really an issue.    And as I mentioned if I use another location on a well known street it works just fine.

Comment: What about moving just slightly next to the marker (add some small offset to the latitude + longitude of the marker), if you are moving directly on top of it, that may be the issue.